# Edit date in row javafx

Tags: java, javafx

How to double click to edit date like email. please help me!
I just learned 1 week

```
TableColumn<datadetail, String> id = 
                new TableColumn<datadetail, String>("Id");
TableColumn<datadetail, String> email = 
                new TableColumn<datadetail, String>("Email");
TableColumn<datadetail, Date> datum = 
                new TableColumn<datadetail, Date>("Datum");
```

```
email.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));
email.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<datadetail> forTableColumn());
email.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<datadetail, String> event) -> {
        TablePosition<datadetail, String> pos = event.getTablePosition();
        String newEmail = event.getNewValue();
        int row = pos.getRow();
        datadetail datadetail = event.getTableView().getItems().get(row);
        datadetail.setEmail(newEmail);
     });
```

Comment: _"edit date like email"_ its not clear what you want to do. Can you please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: I doubleclick to edit date in table like this image https://lankydanblog.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/tableexample4.png?w=502